# Metrics in raw in Google Looker Studio

Tags: excel, google-bigquery, pivot-table, looker-studio

I have following question on looker studio pivot table,

On my looker studio that's what I have as a basic pivot table :

| Pays | nb command | CA Brut | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FR | 104 | 40956 | 132 |
| ES | 9 | 6700 | 12 |
| DE | 27 | 12800 | 33 |

and that's what I have on my excel pivot table and I want to reproduce on looker studio :

| Pays | metrics | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FR | nb command | 104 |
|  | CA brut | 40956 |
|  | Quantity | 132 |
| ES | nb command | 9 |
|  | CA brut | 6700 |
|  | Quantity | 12 |

Do you know how could I pass the metrics in raws like before ?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

If your raw table is located in BigQuery, then use the Looker Studio Custom Query and replace your raw table source after the `from`:

```sql
With demo_tbl as (
SELECT "FR" as Pays, 104 as nb, 40956 as CA_Brut, 132 as Quantity
union all select "ES",  9,6700, 12
union all select "DE",  27, 12800,  33
)

SELECT * from demo_tbl
unpivot( value_column_name for metrics_column_name in (nb,CA_Brut,Quantity) )
```

If your table comes from Sheets or any other data source besides BigQuery, you need a workaround, since Looker Studio does not support unnesting a table. Please use the Blend in Looker Studio under the menu resources. Add a new blend with your table and a dummy table containing a column `DUMMMY` with the number 1 to 3 and use the cross join between these tables. In your table use the blend as data source and as dimension, please add the column `Pays`. Please add in the dimension of the table a formula with

```
case when DUMMY=1 then "nb" 
when DUMMY=2 then "CA_Brut"
when DUMMY=3 then "Quantity"
end
```

Please add in the metrics of the table a same formula, but without quotations:

```
case when DUMMY=1 then nb 
when DUMMY=2 then CA_Brut
when DUMMY=3 then Quantity
end
```